# Simply display distance in KM between two points

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I can't find a simple answer to this so here it goes.

I'm fetching Latitude and longitude coordinates from a wordpress post. I put them in an array to initialize my markers as such (ignore the timeouts and stuff, I just wanted the markers to drop 1 by 1..):

```
function initMarkers(){
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        setTimeout(function(y){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[y][2], locations[y][1]),
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: iconMarker
            })
            gmarkers.push(marker);//Adds the marker object to array

            //console.log(gmarkers[i].getPosition());

        },500 * i, i);// end setTimeout

    }// end for 
}
```

This works without a problem. Notice that I add the marker object to "gmarkers" to be able to eventually use its parameters.

At this point, the map appears, the markers drop and there are no errors.

I'm also storing the user's geolocation in "userPos".

```
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            /*var userPos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                             position.coords.longitude);*/
             userPos = google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
           position.coords.longitude);

          }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
```

Now comes my problem. How do I get the distance from the user's position to each marker?

I've tried all sorts of things like the ascynchronous "computeDistanceBetween" but it's giving my undefined variable errors and apparently there might be a synch issue and whatnot... (which would explain the undefined variables).

Is there a simple solution ?

Comment: ` ascynchronous "computeDistanceBetween"` - computeDistanceBetween is _not_ asynchronous.  Your geolocation and initMarkers functions both take time to complete however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to compute the great-circle distance between two points is to use the haversine formula.

You can get the distance (d  variable in the script) by doing:

```
Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
   return this * Math.PI / 180;
}

var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```